# Does TiDB Serverless support TiFlash for analytical jobs (OLAP) just like TiDB?

Tags: serverless, olap, tidb, analytical, mpp

In TiDB, I can configure and deploy TiFlash, which can be used for columnar based storage to perform OLAP tasks. In TiDB Serverless, I can see the same columnar storage is available on the dashboard. I want to use TiFlash too in TiDB Serverless.

But when I tried to run ALTER TABLE table_name SET TIFLASH REPLICA count; to create the TiFlash replica, it did not work.
Are there other configurations I have to run through to enable it in the TiDB Serverless?

I tried command: ALTER TABLE table_name SET TIFLASH REPLICA count;
It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Really？I remember it's support , what's the error message？

Comment: This might be better as a comment instead of an answer. Alternatively, perhaps a link to the documentation would be more helpful to the original poster?

Answer (score 1):

This indeed should work. Could you check if you get any warnings for the `ALTER TABLE... SET TIFLASH REPLICA...` statement?

What does `TABLE information_schema.tiflash_replica;` return?

See also: https://docs.pingcap.com/tidbcloud/create-tiflash-replicas#check-replication-progress